# how to write a program for addition of two numbers in google test?

Tags: googletest

I am working with visual studio 2005...
Can anybody tell me how to write most basic program for addition of two numbers in google test??
I have gone through almost all the references given...but somehow didnt understand how to get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would be about as basic as it can get:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

int GetSum(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

TEST(MathsFunctions, GetSum) {
  ASSERT_EQ(3, GetSum(1, 2));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

You need to provide the path to gtest's include directory and link to gtest.lib